# Duplicate Results When Sending Email

Tags: python

My code below, opens up X amount of URL's using Selenium and iterates through them. I check if 'missing_amounts' is in icl_dollar_amount. If it is then I scrape the data in website and store them in lists. If not, i am appending the amounts in another list and sending an email using the function sendMissingFileEmail(getFileName(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor, amount_ack_missing_l)). The issue I am having is that I am getting a ton of duplicate emails and I have a feeling its because the two For loops in my file2.py. One of them i am iterating over URLs to opens several links, and the other for loop is to iterate over a list to get missing amounts. FYI if i comment out the else:amount_ack_missing_l.append(amount) block, the duplicate emails stop but that I because it has the email function in it.

expected results:

```
Missing filename Test in the amount of $40,752.25
Missing filename Test2 in the amount of $64,452.96
```

actual results:

```
Missing filename Test in the amount of $40,752.25
Missing filename Test2 in the amount of $64,452.96
Missing filename Test in the amount of $40,752.25
Missing filename Test2 in the amount of $64,452.96
Missing filename Test in the amount of $40,752.25
Missing filename Test2 in the amount of $64,452.96
```

file2.py

```
def scrapeBOAWebsite(url,fcg_subject_l, gp_subject_l):

    from ICL_Awk_Checker import  rps_amount_l2

    icl_dollar_amount_l = []
    file_date_l = []
    company_id_l = []
    client_id_l = []
    customer_name_l = []
    file_name_l = []
    file_total_l = []
    item_count_l = []
    file_status_l = []
    amount_ack_missing_l = []


    for link in url:
        print(link)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                                   executable_path=r'\\TEST\user$\TEST\Documents\driver\chromedriver.exe')
        # if 'P2 Cust ID 908554 File' in fcg_subject:
        browser.get(link)
        username = browser.find_element_by_name("dialog:username").get_attribute('value')
        if 'test@email.com' in username:
            try:
                password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dialog:password']").send_keys('PPCsm2021$')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                    print("Incorrect Username/Password")
        elif 'test2@email.com' in username:
            try:
                password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dialog:password']").send_keys('TEST123')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("Incorrect Username/Password")
        submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dialog:continueButton']").click()
        body = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Total:')]").text
        icl_dollar_amount = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0]
        if not missing_amount:
            logging.info("List is empty")
            print("List is empty")
        for amount in missing_amount:
            print(amount)
            if amount in icl_dollar_amount:
                icl_dollar_amount_l.append(icl_dollar_amount)
                file_name_l.append(get_file_name)
                get_file_total = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0].split('$',1)[1]
                file_total_l.append(get_file_total)
                get_item_count = body.split("Number of Items:")[1].split(' ')[1].strip()
                item_count_l.append(get_item_count)
                get_file_date = body.split("Receipt Time:")[1].split("\n\n")[0].strip()
                file_date_l.append(get_file_date)
                get_file_status = body.split("Status:")[1].split("\n\n")[0].strip()
                file_status_l.append(get_file_status)
            else:
                amount_ack_missing_l.append(amount)
                logging.info("Missing Files " + str(amount))
                print("Missing  Files " + str(amount))
     if amount_ack_missing_l:
            sendMissingFileEmail(getFileName(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor, amount_ack_missing_l))

    return icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l, company_id_l, client_id_l, customer_name_l, file_name_l, file_total_l, \
           item_count_l, file_status_l, amount_ack_missing_l


def getFileName(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor, amount_ack_missing_l):
    cd = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    cd = cd.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    missing_file_l = []


    for amount in amount_ack_missing_l:
         rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}' """
         rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()
         for rps in rps_table_results:
            rps_amount_f = str(rps[18]).rstrip('0')
            rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
            rps_amount_l2.append(rps_amount_f)
            missing_file = "Missing filename " + rps[6] + " in the amount of $" + rps_amount_f
            missing_file_l.append(missing_file)

    return missing_file_l


def sendMissingFileEmail(missing_file_l):

    ## START OF EMAIL SCRIPT

    # Define variables to construct email
    addr_from = 'test@email.com'
    addr_to = 'test@email.com'
    smtp_server = 'email.test.com'
    port = '25'

    subject = '**Missing File**'
    for missing_file in missing_file_l:
        html = f"""
                   {missing_file}
                   """
        # Construct email
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = addr_from
        msg['To'] = addr_to
        # rcpt = bcc.split(";") + [addr_to]
        body = html

        # Attach HTML to body and
        attachHTML = MIMEText(body, 'html')
        msg.attach(attachHTML)

        # Add Server and Port to SMTP Object
        s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)

        # Send email with defined variables
        s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()


icl_dollar_amount_l, file_date_l, company_id_l, client_id_l, customer_name_l, file_name_l, 
file_total_l, item_count_l,file_status_l, amount_ack_missing_l = scrapeBOAWebsite(url, fcg_subject_l, 
gp_subject_l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `scrapeBOAWebsite()` function, this part:

```
  if amount_ack_missing_l:
        sendMissingFileEmail(getFileName(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor, amount_ack_missing_l))
```

... is indented (by only one space, but it still counts) under the main loop:

```
for link in url:
```

So you're sending the entire email list *each time* through the loop.

Comment: ahhh yes that was the issue! Now im having another duplicating issue on else:
                amount_ack_missing_l.append(amount)